# Converting a string character-by-character to an NSMutableString in loop

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to get each individual character of a string, `gameWord`, into an `NSMutableArray`. 
I'm converting each `char` into an object and then adding the objects into the `NSMutableArray` with the following code:

```
NSMutableString *letterOne = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%C",[gameWord characterAtIndex:0]];

NSMutableString *letterTwo = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%C",[gameWord characterAtIndex:1]];
```

and so on....

What I don't understand is why the following loop won't work?

```
NSMutableArray *lettersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[gameWord length]];

for (int x = 0 ; x <= [gameWord length] ; x++) {

    NSMutableString *letter = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%C",[gameWord characterAtIndex:x]];

       [lettersArray addObject:letter];
       [letter release];
    }
```

Would really appreciate help understanding this problem and any other ways of getting each character of an `NSString` into individual objects (not `char`s).

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop goes beyond the length of the string. Arrays are zero-based, so the last object has the index `[gameWord length] - 1`.

This should work:

```
for (int x = 0; x < [gameWord length]; x++) {
    //...         ^--changed from <= to <
}
```